# Seemingly Simple Query in Pl Sql

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a table "defects" in the following format:

```
id   status  stat_date   line   div  area
1    Open    09/21/09    F      A    cube
1    closed  01/01/10    F      A    cube
2    Open    10/23/09    B      C    Back
3    Open    11/08/09    S      B    Front
3    closed  12/12/09    S      B    Front
```

My problem is that I want to write a query that just extracts the "Open" defects.  If I write a query to simply extract all open defects, then I get the wrong result because there are some defects, 
that have 2 records associated with it.  For example, with the query that I wrote I would get defect id#s 1 and 3 in my result even though they are closed.  I hope I have explained my problem well.  Thank you.

Comment: Is this a problem with your data?  Should there be two entries in there with the same ID?

Comment: The problem is definetly with the data but that is what they give me so I have to try to work with it.

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM DEFECTS t
  JOIN (SELECT d.id,
               MAX(d.stat_date) 'msd'
          FROM DEFECTS d
      GROUP BY d.id) x ON x.id = t.id
                      AND x.msd = t.stat_date
 WHERE t.status != 'closed'
```

1. The join is getting the most recent date for each `id` value.
2. Join back to the original table on based on the `id` and `date` in order to get only the most recent rows.
3. Filter out those rows with the closed status to know the ones that are currently open

Answer (score 1):

```
Select * 
from defects d
where status = 'Open'
and not exists (
   select 1 from defects d1
   where d1.status = 'closed'
   and d1.id = d.id
   and d1.stat_date > d.stat_date
)
```

Answer (score 1):

So you want to get the most recent row per `id` and of those, only select those that are open.  This is a variation of the common [greatest-n-per-group](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/greatest-n-per-group) problem.

I would do it this way:

```
SELECT d1.*
FROM defects d1
LEFT OUTER JOIN defects d2
  ON (d1.id = d2.id AND d1.stat_date < d2.stat_date)
WHERE d2.id IS NULL
  AND d1.status = 'Open';
```

Comment: Would you say this typically performs better than the group by method? My instincts tell me no, as you must do a date comparison on every record, but have not tested this.

Comment: This works great.  Thanks a million because I was working on this for a few days and I was getting really frustrated.

Comment: @OrbMan: Which solution performs better depends on the RDBMS implementation and your specific data set, so one should test both queries on real data to be sure.  I would hope the RDBMS can compare two dates efficiently, especially if they're indexed.

Answer (score 0):

This should get what you want.  I wouldn't have a record for open and closing a defect, rather just a single record to track a single defect.  But that may not be something you can change easily.

```
SELECT id FROM defects 
WHERE status = 'OPEN' AND id NOT IN 
(SELECT id FROM defects WHERE status = 'closed')
```

Comment: Thank you.  This works very well.  I am amazed at how many different ways there are to get the correct results.  Thank you again.  Defects are not allowed to be re-opened so at least I don't have to worry about that.  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

This query handles multiple opens/closes/opens, and only does one pass through the data (i.e. no self-joins):

```
SELECT * FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT
        id
       ,FIRST_VALUE(status)
        OVER (PARTITION BY id
              ORDER BY stat_date desc)
        as last_status
       ,FIRST_VALUE(stat_date)
        over (PARTITION BY id
              ORDER BY stat_date desc)
        AS last_stat_date
       ,line
       ,div
       ,area
 FROM defects)
WHERE last_status = 'Open';
```